# MS Access Report - Multiple Grouping issue

Tags: ms-access, report, ms-access-2010

This should be a rather simple fix but I'm not sure how to go about it.

I'm creating a Task List that has Categories, Tasks, Sub Task and Last Task in separate tables.  I've made them join under their respective IDs in Relationships.

Ultimately, I would like to create a Report with these 4 tables. I've grouped it in the Report by Category ID, Task ID, Sub Task ID etc. BUT, my problem is that if there is not a Sub Task or Last Task, all other Tasks and Categories do not sure up either. How do I make it so that even if a Task does not have a Sub Task, that it shows up in the report?

Thank you!

Comment: Please update the post with the SQL you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you investigate using `LEFT JOIN` for the query below your report.

This [blog Post by Jeff Atwood](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) is a very good explanation of the different types of joins.